# Magento 1 price reload function for custom option is called as many times as options are present

Tags: magento-1, custom-options

I have a long list of custom option for a product. it's around 5000 options (multiple select) inside the custom option. And I found that it's extremely slow each time when I select or unselect an option because there is a javascript function **optionsPrice.reload()** is called (from **reloadPrice** function) so as to reflect the price. But the worse part is that function call occurs 5000 times when I select or unselect an option.

After I take **optionsPrice.reload()** out of the looping, it becomes fast and seems works all fine. My question is actually to ask is there a particular reason put **optionsPrice.reload()** inside the looping or just mistakenly leave there?